# Driving parallel MOSFETs individually

Tags: arduino, mosfet, gate-driving

I have two MOSFETs in my circuit and I want to make it possible to actuate them individually and simultaneously, depending on what analog input I am giving with the joystick.

Do I need one gate driver for each MOSFET or is it possible to use one gate driver for both?

How do I make it possible to individually actuate the MOSFETs?

Comment: If you need to use gate drivers then you'll need two.

Answer (score 4):

First: check whether you actually *need* a gate driver at all. There's so-called "logic level MOSFETs" that can well be switched using typical microcontroller output voltages. A gate driver has the function of allowing higher drive voltages, and faster charging/discharging than the current-limited pins of a microcontroller allow. You might not be in a situation to require that at all! And: 100 kΩ between gate driver and gate seems *much* too high, that sounds like you're not actually sure what you need there. It fully negates the drive strength advantages of a gate driver, so much that together with the two gate capacitances of the MOSFETs that you attached there you *ensure* you have an uneven, slow start – worst case for the MOSFETs.

The point of a gate driver is to be able to drive the gate. So, I don't see how you can use one driver to drive two FETs individually. If you need a gate driver to control your FETs, you will need one per channel.

Comment: I've added another gate driver to each mosfet. Would it work now?

Comment: better. But I still don't see why you need a gate driver, and without knowing driver and MOSFET datasheets, nobody can tell you whether it works.

Comment: this is engineering, not *guessing*. You need to be able to put into words why you need a gate driver.

Answer (score 2):

According to your schematic diagram, the MOSFETs are not in parallel. They drive different loads.

If you use gate drivers you need one for each MOSFET.

If you use logic level FETs that you can drive directly from the Arduino, then you will not need the gate drivers.

In any case you will need two outputs from the Arduino.

Using code turn on either one or both outputs as is required.